# has_one unitialized constant when using .build_

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have situation where an assignment has one training session associated with it

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :trainingsession
end

class TrainingSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assignment
  has_many :drills
end
```

I keep getting a `uninitialized constant` error when I'm trying to build an object with a has_one relationship

I'm using the following to build the training session in my controller

```
@activetrainingsession = @assignment.build_trainingsession
```

And that line blows up with the `uninitialized constant`

Something that seems like it should be straightforward!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, Rails uses [camelize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/camelize) and [underscore](http://apidock.com/rails/String/underscore) to switch between camel case and underscored representations. This means, in your case, that `TrainingSession` would be properly referenced as `training_session` (not `trainingsession`).

You need:

`@activetrainingsession = @assignment.build_training_session`

But, to follow said convention all the way through,  it may be better as:

`@active_training_session = @assignment.build_training_session`

Comment: Thanks Brad - you got me on the path to a solution. The actual code above didn't work for me but I explicity named the class in the model i.e. `class_name: 'TrainingSession' and that worked.